# Recording profiling logs of a particular database instead of entire mongodb

Tags: mongodb, profiling, database

I want to track(recording logs of) a particular database at a time instead of entire mongodb.I don't know if it is possible or not.
I have a large no of databases and several users can access any of the databases.In case I want to see profiling logs of all the queries to a single database it will be quite a overhead
to recognize the queries to that database from mixed records of queries of hundreds of databases.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) can be enabled at either:

- a **global** level using the [`profile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) setting in your configuration file or the equivalent `--profile` command line argument
- a **per-database** level using the [`db.setProfilingLevel()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel) command

The default level for profiling is `0` (none). Other options include `1` (profile slow queries) and `2` (profile all queries).

The default value for "slow" queries is 100ms. This can be adjusted at a global level using the [`slowms`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#slowms) configuration option, or per-database as the second parameter for `db.setProfilingLevel()`.

Comment: Hi Stennie,thanx for your response but this is what I've already read about in docs.I have to find a way following which I can record the profiling logs in to a log file(this file may be custom though) on per -database basis.currently the data is being stored in to a collection named 'system.profile'.

Comment: You can [increase the size of the profiling database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#change-size-of-system-profile-collection) if you want to capture more history. If you want to capture via log files, it's going to be more work to separate out by namespace. Typically profiling is about sampling rather than capturing unlimited history. What are you trying to achieve, and what O/S are you using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and I want to record profiling of particular database  which is currently being accessed by node js,actually I'm trying to write a script in which I'll specify a particular database and executing this script will provide all the queries from node.js to this database.Probably script will include setting profiling level '2' for that db first then writing logs and displaying then I can change profiling status '0' later when monitoring is done.

Comment: Actually the requirement has been changed a little. Now I've to intercept queries from a particular page using node.js.Is there any such interceptor in mongodb.